# Selenium webdriver- Click on moving espot images - Amazon.in

Tags: image, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, e-commerce

I am trying to learn selenium by automating amazon.in
I would like to click on a moving image in an e-spot. It seems there is no class or id. Then how can i proceed?

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get("http://amazon.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();     
        WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='nav_cat_2']"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    
        builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav_a nav_item' and .=\"All Books\"]")));
        WebElement menuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav_a nav_item' and .=\"All Books\"]"));
        menuOption.click();
```

I have reached on the page. But dont know how to proceed after that.

```
URL
http://www.amazon.in/Books/b/ref=nav_shopall_books_all/280-9259056-7717210?_encoding=UTF8&node=976389031
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, the images are getting scrolled, so just wait for the concerned image first and then click on it. I have added a code based on that:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='acsux-hero-wrap']//li[2]//img")));

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='acsux-hero-wrap']//li[2]//img"));
ele.click();
```

**In the above code, the driver waits till the visibility of the 2nd image is located under 60 seconds. Then, it clicks on that element.**

Similarly you can just replace the number **li[2]** with **"li[1]"** for first element, "**li[4]**" for fourth element, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use other attributes such as width or alt

//img[contains(@alt,'Children')]

I was able to click on the highlighted image shown in your screenshot although its a different image with different keywords i reckon you'll need some bonded attribute for that image there to be able to click it regardless of its content or so and that'll be something like know the exact div the img tag this and so on.

hope this helps